# Plot GLM Regression Equation and Rsquared on GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have a problem like this:

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
a <- mtcars
reorganized <- a %>% gather (-mpg, key = "var", value = "value")

g <- ggplot(reorganized, aes(y = value, x = var)) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=TRUE, fill=NA, 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"), fullrange = F) +
  geom_smooth(method="glm", fill='red',
              method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
  stat_regline_equation(
    aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~"))
  )+
  geom_point(aes(), alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~var, nrow=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

The data is the `reorganized` dataframe, with 3 columns: mpg, var, value

Using this code, I want plot facet with logistic regression line, equation with scatter plot. However, the formula appears incorrect, they only has the form of `y = b + ax`, and sometimes the Radj is out of the plot
[image]

How can I draw the correct formula of logistic regression in this figure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use the glm method for non-categorical variables. This won't work. Instead, you should use either "loess" or "lm" methods. Also, to insert correctly the equation inside each facet you can control the position and the size of the equation. The code would be the following (geom_smooth defaults to "loess"):

```
ggplot(reorganized, aes(y = value, x = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(se=TRUE, fill=NA, method.args=list(family="gaussian"), fullrange = F) +
  stat_regline_equation( aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., 
                                             sep = "~~~~")),
                         label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top", size = 2)+
  geom_point(aes(), alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~var, nrow=2)+
  theme_bw()
```

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PVr5.jpg)

By default, geom_smooth is set to the loess method with the formula y ~ x. That is why you only have y and x on the equations. If you want a different formula you should look for how to customize formulas in geom_smooth.

Comment: Hi, the mtcar is just the toy dataset. My concern is how to draw the logistic function, or generally, all other function in ggplot.

As in your image, the functions still appear incorrect, they are not the linear equation as in the plot

Comment: I still think your problem may be that you are trying to use glm for non-categorical variables. Try first to use glm (formula = y~x) and see if that works. If it works, to draw a 'correct' logistic regression, you will probabliy have to provide a column of the datafrmae with the formula you want. Otherwise, stat_smooth will present something more linear than we're used to.

Comment: I tried briefly this a<-data.frame(v1 = sample(c(0,1), 50, replace= TRUE), v2 = sample(c(0:25), 50, replace = TRUE), v3 = sample(c("a", "b"), 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(a, aes(v2,v1))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), formula=y~x)+facet_wrap(~v3) 
and it seem to work

Comment: No I think we are talking about two different thing right now.

Comment: I guess that you are trying to answer to "fitting" problem, which is not my focus in here. What I'm asking in here is how to visualize the actual formula on the plot